# How to execute rskeymgmt utility silently in windows server 2008

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, command-line-interface

When i run **reskeymgmt.exe** - to create a backup copy of the encryption key, it responses

> "Are you sure want to extract the key from the Report Server? Yes (y)/
>   No (n)?"

I found this [link](http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-reporting-services/how-to-run-the-rskeymgmt-command-silently-49430.shtml) which helps me to automate the execution of reskeymgmt commmand in windows xp and server 2003. The suggestion looks like:

```
rskeymgmt -e -f a:\backupkey\keys -p "password" < "C:\Yes.txt"
```

But when i move to windows server 2008, this tip won't work because the command prompts the confirmation in another console.

Does anyone knows a trick to fix this issue in windows server 2008?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Per [here](http://dbaspot.com/ms-sqlserver/232723-rskeymgmt-switch-say-yes.html),

You could try using a pipe:

`echo Y | rskeymgmt [parameters]`

Comment: it doesn't work. A confirmation window still pop-ups